# Graphics3D quality degradation when rotating since Mathematica 12.1

Tags: graphics3d, rendering, version-12.1

[image]
Anti-aliasing is no longer effective when I rotate 3D graphics with mouse, this problem was introduced since version 12.1.
I don't like this feature, I tried to modify the render engine, found that only `"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"` works.
However, there are some problems with this approach, mouse interaction performance is very low.
For example:

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[x]Sin[y]+Cos[y]Sin[z]+Cos[z]Sin[x]==0,{x,-2π,2π},{y,-2π,2π},{z,-2π,2π},
  Mesh->None,BaseStyle->RenderingOptions->{"3DRenderingEngine"->"Mesa"}]
```

Are there any valid options to return to previous features?
I am using Mathematica 11.3 and Mathematica 12.1 on windows10 20H2 with discrete graphics, anti-aliasing quality has been set to the highest.

Comment: `RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa", 
  "3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTreeOrDepthBuffer"}` ?

Comment: @cvgmt Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.